# Reallocating/Erasing numpy array vs. new allocation in loop

Tags: arrays, memory-management, numpy

In my program I need to work with arrays roughly 500x500 to 1500x1500 within a function that is looped over 1000's of times. In each iteration, I need to start with an array that has the same form (whose dimensions are fixed across all iterations). The initial values will be:

```
[0 0 0 ... 1]
[0 0 0 ... 1]
....
```

However, the contents of the array will be modified within the loop. What is the most efficient way to "reset" the array to this format so I can pass the same array to the function every time without having to allocate a new set of memory every time? (I know the range of rows that were modified)

I have tried:

```
a[first_row_modified:last_row_modified,:] = 0.
a[first_row_modified:last_row_modified,:-1] = 1.
```

but it takes roughly the same amount of time as just creating a new array every time with the following:

```
a = zeros((sizeArray, sizeArray))
a[:,-1] = 1.
```

Is there a faster way to effectively "erase" the array and change the last column to ones? I think this is similar to this question, [clearing elements of numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514394/clearing-elements-of-numpy-array) , although my array doesn't change sizes and i didn't see the definitive answer to the previously asked question.

Comment: Have you done any profiling? Does resetting the array actually take up a significant amount of the processing time?

Comment: Just out of curiosity have you profiled your code, does this take a noticeable amount of time? On my machine doing this 1000's of times take less than 2sec.

Comment: I have profiled the code. The majority of the time is spend doing linear algebra in numpy linked to MKL. I've optimized everything else, but in the profile, it says that 3% of the time is spent in the zeros function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; I think the way you are doing it is about as fast as it gets.